# Entity Framework 6 - Only one entity returned on duplicates

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, foreign-keys, entity

I have an issue where multiple relations to the same entity (Product) only returns a single entity.
The model looks like this:

```
public class Package
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framework have created a relational table for me.

If I have more than one relation to the same Product, only one entity is returned for that Product.
The reason I want more of the same Product on a Package, is that I want to use Count() for getting a quantity value, instead of having a Count column (which will rarely be used for anything other than 1).

Here are the relations in the database:

[image]

When I retrieve Package of ID 22 from the database, the Product IDs returned are:

[image]

Here you can see Product of ID 8 is only listed once.

This is how data is retrieved:

[image]

OnModelCreating overwrite

[image]

My only thought so far is that EF might see Product 8 as one entity, no matter how many times it is listed, as there are no primary keys in the relational table.

Has anyone experienced this and have an idea to overcome the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the code that you used to retrieve the result for package 22?

Comment: Hi, on the "OnModelCreating" what relation configuration you have between the entities?

Comment: @PedroBrito I have added it now, thank you

Comment: the method that you posted is to retrieve the package, i want the method that you use to retrieve the products from a determined package pls.